# Recoding Dates in nested data to continuous long file with for loop in R

Tags: r

I am struggling a little with the logic for recoding nested data into a long "continuous" format based on dates in R

Below is a dummy example of my data. I have three sets of dates The start and stop time for a participant that is stored in long format, and then the start of another incident that is stored as wide data.

[image]

```
  GC_ID   HMIS_Start   HMIS_Stop   CPS Start   CPS Start 2   CPS Start 3  
 ------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- ------------- 
      1   1/10/14      1/20/14     1/15/14     6/2/14        NA           
      1   4/10/14      5/30/14     1/15/14     6/2/14        NA           
      1   12/1/14      12/2/14     1/15/14     6/2/14        NA           
      1   1/1/15       2/28/15     1/15/14     6/2/14        NA           
      2   8/13/13      8/17/14     NA          NA            NA           
      3   5/1/15       5/2/15      1/16/13     6/26/14       7/27/15      
      3   6/4/16       7/10/16     1/16/13     6/26/14       7/27/15      
      4   10/15/13     10/25/13    2/18/15     NA            NA           
      4   12/25/13     1/18/14     2/18/15     NA            NA           
      4   2/8/15       7/20/15     2/18/15     NA            NA
```

My goal is to create two long continuous variables that go along with each months from August 2013 to December 2015. For one of the two variables, I would like to code a 1 for each month that target month is within an HMIS_start and HMIS_stop time for a participant AND has at least one CPS Start date within that month. The second variable would do a similar thing, but it would be if the CPS Start date happened in the month after the HMIS Stop date.

So participant 1's data could look like this:

[image]

I assume I need to create a blank data set with the ID variable and then the month/year variable. Then I would use a for loop for each ID to run an "if_then" statement comparing IF the month is greater then the HMIS start and less then the HMIS stop AND if the CPS start is within that month too.

I am mostly just struggling with how to create that process and use the for loop logically given that there are long data already in the file and multiple lines of long data per participant that need to be compared to all possible CPS start dates

Any thoughts or code tips on how to tackle this?

Comment: You're going to get more responses if you use text and not images.  Using images requires someone to type all the data manually instead of copying.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I think I imported the original table correctly!

Comment: In row 4, you have "2/30/15". There is only 28 days in Feb. Please correct.

Comment: Also, why is `CPS_After` in your final dataset for `Jun-14` = 1. There is no `Jun-14` for any `GC_ID = 1`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you came to your answers, and I will update this code once that is provided. But I used `library(tidyverse)` and `library(lubridate)` for this:

```
dat <- data.frame(GC_ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4), 
                  HMIS_Start = c("1/10/14", "4/10/14", "12/1/14", "1/1/15", "8/13/13", "5/1/15", "6/4/16", "10/15/13", "12/25/13","2/8/15"), HMIS_Stop = c("1/20/14", "5/30/14", "12/2/14", "2/28/15", "8/17/14", "5/2/15", "7/10/16", "10/25/13", "1/18/14", "7/20/15"), CPS_Start = c("1/15/14","1/15/14","1/15/14","1/15/14",NA, "1/16/13", "1/16/13", "2/18/15", "2/18/15", "2/18/15"), CPS_Start_2 = c("6/2/15", "6/2/15", "6/2/15", "6/2/15", NA, "6/26/14", "6/26/14", NA, NA, NA), CPS_Start_3 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"7/27/15", "7/27/15", NA,NA,NA))

dats <- dat %>% 
        mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
        mutate_if(is.character, ~as.Date(., format = "%m/%d/%y")) %>%
        gather(Var, Dates, -GC_ID, -HMIS_Start, -HMIS_Stop) %>%
        filter(!is.na(Dates)) %>%
        mutate(HMIS_CPS_SAME = if_else(month(HMIS_Start) == month(HMIS_Stop) &
                                       year(HMIS_Start)  == year(HMIS_Stop)  &
                                       month(HMIS_Start) == month(Dates)     &
                                       year(HMIS_Start)  == year(Dates), 1, 0 ),
               CPS_After     = if_else(month(HMIS_Stop) + 1 == month(Dates) &
                                       year(HMIS_Stop) == year(Dates), 1,0 ),
               Months        = month(HMIS_Start),
               Years         = year(HMIS_Start)) %>%
        arrange(GC_ID, HMIS_Start, Dates) %>%
        group_by(GC_ID, Months, Years) %>%
        summarise(HMIS_CPS_SAME = max(HMIS_CPS_SAME),
                  CPS_After     = max(CPS_After)) %>% 
        ungroup()

full_dat <- merge(data.frame(GC_ID = unique(dat$GC_ID)), data.frame(Dates = seq.Date(as.Date("2013-08-01"), as.Date("2015-12-01"), by = "month"))) %>%
            mutate(Months = month(Dates), Years = year(Dates)) %>% 
            left_join(dats, by = c("GC_ID", "Months", "Years")) %>%
            mutate_if(is.numeric , replace_na, replace = 0)
```

First I created the data in R and R format. Then I converted the data to date format for the 5 columns you mentioned. I made the data long to do the comparisons specified, then found the max for each `GC_ID`, `Months`, `Years`. Then I used a cartesian join for each date and `GC_ID` and got the months and years from those and joined our `dats` to `full_dat` by `GC_ID`, `Months`, `Years`. The last `mutate_if` is to convert all `NA` values to 0. NO Looping Needed! :-)